# H2 database User defined java function Class not found

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, classnotfound

When I create an ALIAS for registering the java function in the H2 database, it gives error of class not found. I am running the h2 database on a tcp connection.

sample,

```
public class TimeFrame { 
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://MYIP:9092/~/test", "sa", "");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        //Setup Table
        stat.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS timeframe");
        stat.execute("CREATE TABLE timeframe (last_updated TIMESTAMP, ip int");
        stat.execute("CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS SLIDEWINDOW FOR \"h2TimeFrame.TimeFrame.slidewindow\" ");
    }
}
```

This is all in pacakge name: h2TimeFrame. To test,

take the sample class "Function" from the org.h2.samples package. how would you run this class on the server with TCP connection. Changing

```
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
```

to

```
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://IPADDRESS:9092/~/test", "sa", "");
```

Comment: Take the sample class "Function" from the org.h2.samples package. how would you run this class on the server with TCP connection. Changing

      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", ""); to
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://IPADDRESS:9092/~/test", "sa", "");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

- The class is `public`
- The method is `public` and `static`
- The class must be available in the classpath of the database engine

  From [H2 Docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions):

  > When referencing a method, the class must already be compiled and included in the classpath where the database is running. Only static Java methods are supported; both the class and the method must be public

Comment: Yes. "in the classpath of the database engine" in this case means it has to be in the classpath of the server (in the process / JVM where the database server is running)

Comment: It might be simpler to [declare the user defined function is defined as source code](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions). That way it is automatically available on the server.

Comment: @javadevil, I did made sure about the 3 things u mentioned and they are also in the documentation. But, didnt worked. For the above given sample class (TimeFrame), if I make a runnable jar and include it in the classpath when starting the server (org.tools.server), should it work? as its not working! am i missing something here